# State Implemented Type once for all generics?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have the following class signature:

```
public class CostZoneEffectivityViewModel : CustomerViewModel, IViewModel, ISQLFilter<CostZoneEffectivityView>, IRefresh<CostZoneEffectivityView>, ITotal<CostZoneEffectivityView>
```

Notice how the Type parameter for the last three interfaces are `CostZoneEffectivityView` which is rather long both in name and class signature.

I was wondering if there was a way to tell it once to make it a little easier on the eyes (i.e. Shorten it)?

Perhaps something like:

```
ISQLFilter<T>, IRefresh<T>, ITotal<T> where T is CostZoneEffectivityView
```

Is there anything that will allow me to shorten the class signature without changing functionality?

Comment: Shorten the class name?

Comment: With [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can alias a type using a [`using` alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)

```
using CZEV = CostZoneEffectivityView;    
...    
public class CostZoneEffectivityViewModel : CustomerViewModel, 
         IViewModel, 
         ISQLFilter<CZEV>, 
         IRefresh<CZEV>, 
         ITotal<CZEV>
```

Is this a good idea? probably not.

If you commonly use those 3 interfaces together, you might also consider wrapping them up together:

```
public interface ICombinedFunctionality<T> // bad name, but you get the idea
            : ISQLFilter<T>, 
             IRefresh<T>, 
             ITotal<T>
{}
```

You then only need it once on your class definition:

```
public class CostZoneEffectivityViewModel : CustomerViewModel, 
         IViewModel, 
         ICombinedFunctionality<CostZoneEffectivityView>
...
```

Comment: I just learned this recently too *facepalm* don't know why I didn't think of that haha. Kept getting myself wrapped up in trying stuff like my example haha. Thanks.

Comment: It syntax highlights too, I love you.